# How to detect the enviorment and place value in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, object, google-analytics

I would like to know how to apply google analytics id for staging/local and production,

I have two ID's, each for staging/local and production. I am using nodejs as a backend, and stored the google analytics key in config file using env file

how to pass if local, pass google analytics id ga_local

if prod, pass google analytics id ga_pro in nodejs in the startup

```
app.js
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config');
var app = express();
var ga_id = app.get('env');
ga_id == "development" ? config.ga_local : config.ga_pro;
//how to pass to frontend

.env

ga_local = "UA-XXXX-X",
ga_pro = "UA-YYYY-Y"

config.js

require('dotenv').config();
const config = {
    ga_local: process.env.ga_local,
    ga_pro: process.env.ga_pro
};
module.exports = config;

front end

<script async src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ga_id}'></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to override an environment variable for different test cases in nodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258670/how-to-override-an-environment-variable-for-different-test-cases-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

you can provide mode at the time of running your node server. .

Run your file ->  `node index.js -m prod`

code to access command line arguments.

```
 const program = require('commander');
/* reading commandline parameters */
program
    .version('1.2')
    .option('-m,--mode [type]', 'Running Mode', 'MODE_NOT_PROVIDED')
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log(program.mode); local,prod or dev
```